# how to retrieve data from google ads api reports(geo_performance_report)

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am trying to get the reports such as geo_performance_report, keywords_perfromance_report etc. but I am unable to figure how do to this with the new version of google-ads api.
I tried this way trying to use the new google-ads but was not successful.
is there any other ways to automate this process using Python.

```
def googleads_report(client, client_id, report_type, columns, start_date, end_date):
    client.SetClientCustomerId(client_id)
    report_downloader = googleads_client.GetReportDownloader(version="v201809")

    report = {
        'reportName': 'report-google-campaign-performance',
        'dateRangeType': 'CUSTOM_DATE',
        'reportType': report_type,
        'downloadFormat': 'CSV',
        'selector': {
            'fields': columns,
            'dateRange': {'min': start_date, 'max': end_date}
        }
    }

    file = io.StringIO(report_downloader.DownloadReportAsString(
        report,
        skip_report_header=True,
        skip_column_header=True,
        skip_report_summary=True,
        include_zero_impressions=False)
    )

    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=columns)
    return df


def main(client, customer_id):
    keyword_columns = [
        'Date',
        'AccountDescriptiveName',
        'AdGroupId',
        'AdGroupName',
        'AdGroupStatus',
        'CampaignId',
        'CampaignName',
        'CampaignStatus',
        'CpcBid',
        'Criteria',
        'CriteriaDestinationUrl',
        'ExternalCustomerId',
        'FirstPageCpc',
        'FirstPositionCpc',
        'Id',
        'KeywordMatchType',
        'Labels',
        'QualityScore',
        'SearchImpressionShare',
        'Status',
        'TopOfPageCpc',
        'Clicks',
        'Conversions',
        'Cost',
        'ConversionValue',
        'Impressions',
        'ViewThroughConversions'
    ]
    report_types = [
        'KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT'
    ]

    for report in report_types:
        base_df = pd.DataFrame()
        if report == 'CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT':
            table_suffix = 'campaigns'
            #columns = campaign_columns
        elif report == 'KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT':
            table_suffix = 'keywords'
            columns = keyword_columns
        elif report == 'AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT':
            table_suffix = 'ads'
            #columns = ad_columns

        start_date = '2019-01-01'

        df = googleads_report(client,customer_id, report, columns, start_date, yesterday)
        df = df.applymap(str)

        # Powershell output
        print(df.head())

        # csv output
        df.to_csv('my_path' + table_suffix + '.csv')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # GoogleAdsClient will read the google-ads.yaml configuration file in the
    # home directory if none is specified.
    googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(path="mypath")

    today = datetime.now().date()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    thirty_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=30)

    try:
        main( googleads_client, "#######")
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        print(
            f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status '
            f'"{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:'
        )
        for error in ex.failure.errors:
            print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
            if error.location:
                for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                    print(f"\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}")
            sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your `version='v201809'` you are not using the most up to date version of the google ads api. That version of the API is scheduled for deprecation in [spring 2022](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/release-notes/v201809).

The newest version of the google ads api now uses a query language for their [reporting examples](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/reporting/example).

Google ads provides a [mapping](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/mapping?hl=en) for common reports into the fields required in their query language.

Once your client is [authenticated](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/overview) with a newer version of the API, you can post the Google Ads query to the client.

```py
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("creds")
service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService", version="v9")

#query below pulls all accounts that your MCC has access to
query = """
            SELECT
                customer_client.client_customer,
                customer_client.level,
                customer_client.manager,
                customer_client.id
            FROM customer_client
            WHERE customer_client.manager != True
        """

search_request = client.get_type("SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest")
search_request.customer_id = "1234adswordscustomer_id"
search_request.query = query
response = service.search_stream(search_request)
```

Comment: Hi there! I just know if version 9 is deprecated from google ads, if I want to use the newest version of API google ads which is version 10, did I must change the version to v10? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about the breaking differences between v9 and v10. You would need to check release documentation to make sure that you're not using parts of the graph that were deprecated in the v9 to v10 switch.